# Trigger API call in background from NotificationService using Coroutines or WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, service, push-notification, worker

I want to trigger an api call in my FirebaseMessagingService but I am facing problems when the app is closed.

I have tried injecting a repository directly in the service and perform an api call in onMessageReceived() using a coroutine, but the coroutine gets killed instantly (right after notification gets displayed on my device) and no call is performed.

Then I have replaced the coroutine with an OneTimeWorker which contains the repository inside. Everything well, the worker works as expected, even if I very rapidly close the app after the notification arrives.

However, noting works if the app is closed, the worker doesn't work anymore. So the app is closed, I get the notification in the tray but the call is not performed. I check with Postman to see if the call has been performed so I know for sure that the worker and the call wasn't successful.

This is my code with coroutines:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationsService @Inject constructor(
) : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    
private val serviceJob = Job()
private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + serviceJob)

@Inject
lateinit var repository: NotificationRepository

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
val notification = message.notification
val notificationId: String = message.toIntent().getStringExtra("notificationId") ?: emptyString()

if (notificationId.isNotEmpty()) {
      serviceScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           repository.confirmNotification(notificationId)
      }
}
```

^ I have also tried moving the entire code inside in onMessageReceived in the serviceScope

The other way around with a worker is:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationsService @Inject constructor(
) : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    
@Inject
lateinit var workManager: WorkManager

@Inject
lateinit var repository: NotificationRepository

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
val notification = message.notification
val notificationId: String = message.toIntent().getStringExtra("notificationId") ?: emptyString()

if (notificationId.isNotEmpty()) {
      val builder = Data.Builder()

    builder.putString(
        NotificationConfirmationWorker.NOTIFICATION_WORKER_KEY,
        notificationId
    )

    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val worker =
        OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationConfirmationWorker::class.java)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(builder.build())
            .addTag(NotificationConfirmationWorker.NOTIFICATION_WORKER_TAG)
            .build()

    workManager.enqueue(worker)
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue and make it work while the app is closed?

Comment: Can you add your code where you tried making the call using coroutines.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I have added my code

Comment: Is `repository.confirmNotification(notificationId)` a suspend function?

Comment: @ArpitShukla Yes, all the way up to the ApiService